# How to write list returned from tf.get_collection into a file and read it

Tags: python-2.7, list, pickle, tensorflow

I tried converting into string and store but cannot convert it back to original type

I also tried pickle.dump but its giving the below error

```
raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

My Code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer = tf.train.import_meta_graph('abcd.ckpt.meta')
    restorer.restore(sess,'abcd.ckpt')
    vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
    with open("pickle_target.txt", "wb") as fp:   
        pickle.dump(vars, fp)
```

I need to store the tf.get_collection into a file, edit it and again read it to a list.

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code / example to replicate the issue

Comment: Sorry! I edited it now :) Please look into it

Answer (score 0):

tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) gives you a list of variables, not the values that are stored in those variables. To get the current values of the variables you have to run the variable list in the session:

```
vars_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer = tf.train.import_meta_graph('abcd.ckpt.meta')
    restorer.restore(sess,'abcd.ckpt')
    vars = sess.run(vars_list)
```

Now vars is a normal python list with the current variable values.